# Mixed Shade/Light Grass issues

Tags: grass

I like in Northeastern PA and just bought a new home.  It has about a half acre to it.  Last year they dug a new well and the ruts the truck left planted new grass.  It looks horrible.  The new grass is much fuller and much more lush than the surrounding grass.

Is there a good way to level all of the grass out together?

Secondly, there are a lot of tall trees shading the back portion of the yard.  Currently there is some grass but it's very 'thin' and I mostly don't even bother mowing it because of the lack of visible growth.  I would really like to plan some grass that will grow and be thick, but I have no idea where to start with type etc.   Which grass would grow best in this type of situation?

Comment: Consider committing to the [Gardening and Landscaping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1369/gardening-and-landscaping) proposal, it is close to beta and might be a better fit for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that trying to plant grass in a struggling area is a lost cause.  I have gone with mulch and hostas anymore, or ground cover.

Comment: I don't think that he's having a hard time growing the grass, rather the type of grass he planted has out grown the old grass.

Comment: I haven't even planted any grass yet.  All that is there currently is what was around when I bought the house.  I would like to fail once before I go to the mulch/hostas approach.

Comment: I am thinking maybe a rock / moss garden would be a nice option.